# What does the ending of the Ember series imply about its setting?

Tags: city-of-ember

All the way through the Ember series you think that you're on a post-apocalyptic Earth, and if it weren't for the last three paragraphs of the last book of the series (The Diamond of Darkhold), that would have been perfectly fine...until the last three paragraphs, where, first off, some of the weird stuff in the prequel (Yonnwood) is (sort of) explained, but also, you suddenly realize that ... what? ... this isn't Earth a all but an Earth-like planet with a very similar history that earth learns not to self-destruct by observing... or what?! I'm sooo confused!

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spacecraft didn’t come from Earth. It came from another planet altogether.

> But it isn’t a star at all. Its a small unmanned spacecraft that set
> out toward Earth more than two hundred years ago, after an astronomer
> named Hoyt McCoy, who lived in a town called Yonwood, made the first
> contact between the human race and beings on another world.
>
> <sub>*The Diamond of Darkhold*</sub>

They don’t seek to learn from the mistakes of Earth, but merely to report on it to their home planet.

> But the spacecraft continued its journey, and those who had sent it
> continued to monitor its progress over the many decades of its flight.
> Finally, a few months before Lina and Doon made their trip back to
> Ember, it arrived. It has been collecting data to send back to its
> home planet. It will report that the magnificent and powerful
> civilization it had expected to find seems to have disappeared and
> that a much smaller and humbler one has taken its place. It will
> observe that a great part of this world lies in darkness during the
> night, but not all. In some places, sparks of light shine, not fires,
> but electric lights, bright gleaming spots like diamonds in the
> darkness. The people here seem not to have lost everything that came
> before, the little craft will report. Some of them have survived; some
> of their learning has, too. It seems clear that they are making a new
> start.
>
> <sub>*The Diamond of Darkhold*</sub>

The Ember series is indeed said on a post-apocalyptic version of Earth, as implied by the fact that the spacecraft set off “toward Earth.” The aliens simply come from another planet, and we don’t know much about it.

Comment: Thanks. Weird. Seems like the whole Yonnwood thing, and this, was patched onto the main storyline. Few connections are made between them, and this is a rather bizarre way to end an otherwise terrific series. (BTW, one of the greatest endings of all time is the end of the final book of the Mortal Engines series: A Darkling Plain. I won't ruin it for you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The entire book of Yonwood was bizarre and it happened before everything (since it was a prequel) so you could assume that it would end the way it started. Also, Hoyt never revealed his discovery and I never thought for a moment that Jeane Duprau would ever just leave the fact that he OPENED THE SKY without a conclusion. Also, Torren says several times that he would 'fly high above the Earth in an airplane' only a page before the last three paragraphs. Maybe that other distant planet learns not to self destruct by observing? Sweet theory though. Sounds like a sick book ending.
(of course only Ms. Duprau could answer our questions)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I don't understand how this answers the question.  Please don't post comments as answers, and please try to make your answers as clear as possible.  You might want to take the [tour].